# How to fade in with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

My idea is to fade in to the tab that is loaded.

This code seems like it should work, but it doesn't fade in. What is wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").click(function(event) {
        $("#central").fadeIn("slow").load('page.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that piece of code ? Please clarify.

Comment: @Sayern Seems like he wants to fade in an element and then `load` something into it.

Comment: Your question does not have enough details! Have you included the jQuery framework script? Does #logo exist? Does #central exist? Did you click on #logo? Does page.html exist in the current folder? Did you put this in a `<script>` tag? Are you serving this on a server, or do you have it loaded as file:// from your local computer? Is your computer plugged in? :P

Comment: @Fel: Please describe in detail what you expect to occur and what is actually occurring.

Comment: i add the website to the post, is the source code, search to #cinco please

Comment: You have to hide #central first: `$("#central").hide().fadeIn("slow").load('page.html');`

Comment: @Fel: Awesome. I've now posted it as an answer; please mark it as accepted so that others will know how to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide #central first, before fading it in:

```
$('#central').hide().fadeIn('slow').load('page.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

Jacob's answer is right, of course, but I'd hazard a guess that you probably want to load the html and *then* fade it in?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logo").click(function(event) {
        $("#central").load('page.html', function() {
           $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This would seem to make more sense. Hard to tell what's wrong from the question.